# How to run a windows form application without instailling SQL server studio but access live data from it's database(Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment

I have developed a **windows form application using C# in visual studio.** Everything's perfect but in terms of database i**don't want to install SQL server studio in client's system.**

But **my application has to access data from database which is in server and use the live data(changes on daily basis) to send mails, update few other things.**

Is there any way that i can **achieve this requirement without installing sql server studio in clients system.**

Thanks in advance and please help.

Comment: you have two ways - install sql server in local PC and use it as a server and all clients request to that - or store all data in real server on internet and all clients send request to that server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Studio as you call it, I think you mean SQL Server Management Studio or SSMS is simply a client application that you use to connect to an instance of a SQL Server db either locally on the same machine or remotely.

You should be able to install only SQL Server Database Engine without SSMS on a machine. Run SSMS from another machine and connect to the db.

Comment: thank you but is there any link where i can download only SQL Server Database Engine. Google mostly is driving me to download studio itself. Is it also just like a studio but helps just to access database from the application? or is there any different connection string. thank you. i may sound dumb, but please help.

Comment: You can start here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads there is a free trial version, that is going to send you to the en-us version.

Comment: will this installation over right my existing data base?

Answer (score 0):

if your windows form app has a localdb, it's mandatory you need to have installed SQL server in whatever pc you will run your program.

I had same question than you and my app failed when I run in two pcs that didn't have SQL Server installed.

I recommend you use SQLite which allows handle data base as whatever normal file.